# adding a date amount in length of service calculation

Tags: php, date, joomla

At Joomla 2.5, in the FABRIC 3.0.9 program I have the form, the records of employees, and the other 4 fields that show the employee's work experience. The first field field usually shows the past employee training in previous companies eg 14-08-22 (G-M-D). The second field in the date format shows the start date for the current company eg 21-03-1997 (DMG), and the third calc-field field shows the calculated time from 21-03-1997 to today, for example 20-01-18 (GMD ), And is derived from the code:

```
   `   ` $ Start_date2field = '{workers___prvidanrada}';
If (! Empty ($ start_date2field)) {
   $ Now_date = new DateTime ();
   $ Start_date2field = new DateTime ($ start_date2field);
   $ Since_start = $ start_date2field-> diff ($ now_date);
   Return $ since_start-> format ('% y-% m-% d');
}
Else {
      Return "no data";
}

  I need to add the internship in the fourth calc-field field for example (14-08-22) GMD and present time (20-01-18) GMD so I get total internship (34-10-10) GMD but i do not know how To sum up, help someone who knows. Reply with code. Thank you in advance.`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need both data in date format in order to find diff of them.

> and wrote in simple third field in **text format**(Y-m-d)

I think this is what stops you.